# Why does identical() return FALSE for what are obviously the same objects?

Tags: r

I do not understand the following code.
Why are the following two objects not identical?

```
a <- dim(matrix(nrow=1, ncol=1)); a
# [1] 1 1
identical(a, c(1,1))
# FALSE
```

Comment: run `str` on both

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `dim` returns an *integer vector*. However, `c(1, 1)` is a *floating point vector*. Unfortunately the difference can’t be seen simply by printing their values but you can inspect the `class` of the values, which will show as `integer` and `numeric` (= floating point numbers), respectively.

To get the same result, do the following:

```
identical(a, c(1L, 1L))
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 5):

When you type `?identical`, you will see

> The safe and reliable way to test two objects for being exactly equal.
> It returns TRUE in this case, FALSE in every other case.

However, `c(1,1)` gives a `numeric` array, but `dim` returns the `integer` one, which is not exactly the same class.

---

You can try `all.equal`, which checks the "near equality", e.g.,

```
> all.equal(a,c(1,1)) 
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: `all.equal` is a useful function, but I wouldn’t use it for integer comparisons, and I would even say that this is a code smell (and hides potential issues in the code).

Comment: another possibility would be `all.equal(a, c(1,1), tolerance = 0)`

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes, exactly, I definitely agree with your point, here is just a workaround if OP wants to have a rough estimation of the equality.